# Polygon zkEVM get token balance Error: could not decode result data

Tags: ethers.js, polygon, zkevm

I'm trying to get balance of every erc20 token's balance in polygon zkevm network with using **Ethers.js**

But I'm getting the error:

```
    Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "balanceOf", "signature": "balanceOf(address)" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.11.1)
        at makeError (..project_path/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/utils/errors.js:124:21)
        at assert (..project_path/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/utils/errors.js:143:15)
        at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (..project_path/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/abi/interface.js:772:9)
        at staticCallResult (..project_path/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/contract/contract.js:249:35)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
        at async staticCall (..project_path/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/contract/contract.js:214:24)
        at async Proxy.balanceOf (..project_path/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/contract/contract.js:254:20)
        at async getTokenBalances (..project_path/src/balances.js:32:24){
      code: 'BAD_DATA',
  value: '0x',
  info: { method: 'balanceOf', signature: 'balanceOf(address)' },
  shortMessage: 'could not decode result data'
```

here is my getTokenBalances Method:

```
async function getTokenBalance() {

  let result = [];
  //ERC20 balances
  for (const token of token_list) {
    if (token.chainId == "1101") {
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(token.address, abi, mainnet_provider);
      const balance = (await contract.balanceOf(bridge_address));
      const res = parseFloat(ethers.formatUnits(balance, Number(token.decimals))).toFixed(2);

      if (res != 0) {
        result.push({
          type: "erc20",
          accountAddress: token.address,
          balance: formattedBalance
        });
      }
    }
  };

  return result;
}
```

where token list from: https://github.com/maticnetwork/polygon-token-list/blob/dev/src/tokens/zkevmPopularTokens.json

and bridge address is: "0x2a3DD3EB832aF982ec71669E178424b10Dca2EDe"

What causes the problem, what is the possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

The issue `could not decode result data (value="0x",` usually came from not existed contract at address. One or some address in your list is wrong.

You should add try-catch in your code, and log what address you're calling, when it's fail and try by yourself on explorer.